# how to collect dataset in dataobject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to collect the information of this Json:

```
{"name":"Maltarya","race":"Sylvari","gender":"Female","profession":"Thief","level":80,"equipment":[{"id":4483,"slot":"HelmAquatic","upgrades":[24723]},{"id":59,"slot":"Backpack","upgrades":[24498],"skin":2381},{"id":11805,"slot":"Coat","upgrades":[24815]},{"id":11889,"slot":"Boots","upgrades":[24723]},{"id":11847,"slot":"Gloves","upgrades":[24815]},{"id":11973,"slot":"Helm","upgrades":[24815]},{"id":11763,"slot":"Leggings","upgrades":[24815]},{"id":11931,"slot":"Shoulders","upgrades":[24815]},{"id":39141,"slot":"Accessory1","upgrades":[24545]}]}
```

But i have an error when i want to collect the equipment informations.
My code is:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters/" + name + "?access_token=" + key);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        Personnages perso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Personnages>(responseString);
```

and my Personnages class:

```
class Personnages
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string race { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string profession { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public IList<string> equipment { get; set; }
}
```

The exception i have is: Unexpected token: Error reading string. StartObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize JSON array to a `IList<string>`. However, this array contains objects, but not strings.

You need to implement another one class for these objects and use it in deserialization:

```
class EquipmentItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string slot { get; set; }
    public List<int> upgrades { get; set; }
}

class Personnages
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string race { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string profession { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public List<EquipmentItem> equipment { get; set; }
}

Personnages perso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Personnages>(responseString);
```